How do the 2x2 Sound Bricks work?
How is sound created by the Sound Bricks 4774c01 and 4774c02?
What is inside of them?
What electronic components are used to create this sound?

I don't have one to tear down right now, but I assume the contents are similar to those musical greeting cards that contain a tiny microcontroller and a piezo speaker. See for example steps 1-10 of this.
